# init:get_argument gives crash dump when Flag is master

Tags: erlang

I was trying to get the value for a flag with the name 'master' using init:get_argument(master), which gives me a crash dump. However, if I change 'master' to 'monkey' al works fine. Is master a reserved flag?

I run release 5.10/OTP R16 on Windows 7 32 bit.
This is the code I use:

```
-module(testerl_app).

-behaviour(application).

%% Application callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

%% ===================================================================
%% Application callbacks
%% ===================================================================

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    case init:get_argument(master) of
        {ok, CLIFlag} ->
            io:format("*** info command flag master has value ~p~n", [CLIFlag]);
        _ ->
            io:format("*** info no command flag master~n")
    end,
    testerl_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\testerl>erl -pa ebin -master me -eval "application:start(testerl)"

{error_logger,{{2013,9,27},{10,48,37}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,ker
nel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{no_master,{badrpc,nodedown}}},{off
ender,[{pid,undefined},{name,file_server_2},{mfargs,{file_server,start_link,[]}}
,{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,27},{10,48,37}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application
_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0
.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,
file_server_2,{no_master,{badrpc,nodedown}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{appl
ication_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,in
it_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{me
ssages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{tr
ap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}]
,[]]}
{error_logger,{{2013,9,27},{10,48,38}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{
shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,file_server_2,{no_master,{badrpc,nodedown}}}},{k
ernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kern
el,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,file_server_2,{no_master,{badrpc,nodedown}}
}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kerne
l,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,file_server_2,{no_master,{badrpc,nodedown}}}
},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-master` flag is actually used by Erlang kernel for [file I/O on slave nodes](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/file_server.erl#L281).

Passing a flag to `erl`, while possible and documented, should be avoided. You should either use plain arguments or application environment values. In this latter case, your command line would be:

`$ erl -pa ebin -testerl master value`

And you would retrieve the value with [`application:get_env/1,2,3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_env-1). Environment values can also be embedded into system configuration files used by releases (if you follow OTP design principles).